# Grails 2: Is it possible to use swagger to document the APIs?

Tags: grails, swagger, grails-2.0

I'm attempting to create a prototype (using Grails 2) where we take advantage of swagger for our documentation.

As such, I had included the following in our `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
compile "io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.3"
compile "io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:1.5.3"
```

And then I declared a bean in `resources.groovy` using the `BeanConfig` class provided by the above dependencies. And finally, I had just used the various annotations provided by the `jaxrs` dependency to document the controllers and their methods.

Everything was great until I realized that these are the older versions of swagger (as in, not OAS 3). I'm completely stumped as to how to use the new libraries.

Going through the documentation, I can pull in the dependencies like this in `resources.groovy`:

```
compile "io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:2.0.5"
```

But I have no idea what class I can use to initialize swagger. Where do I defined which packages it needs to scan? What class can I use to generate the swagger JSON?

I realize that there are plugins (like swaggydoc) but these are not maintained, and thus I would rather not use them.
Ideally, I would use the libraries provided by swagger themselves.

It's all just java code, and so I feel like I should be able integrate it with grails 2, especially since it worked with the old swagger libraries. But I need some help getting started.

Comment: Isn't it ironic that you are using old version of Grails but refuse to use dedicated old swagger plugin for this version? Rethink this approach, please.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily ironic, but I get what you're saying. I wish I could upgrade the Grails version, but I'm not in a position to do so. And my issue with the plugins is that they use an older specification. I don't want to to be tied down to an older specification just because of the framework.